# scala: How to obtain class name through complex polymorphism with compile time macros?

Tags: scala, scala-macros

When attempting to get the name of a class via a WeakTypeTag reference when defining a macro implementation, I can't seem to get the proper info if multiple layers of polymorphism are applied.

For example if I have the following setup:

```
object MacroSupport {
  def get_name_impl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context): c.Expr[String] = {
    val nameOfA: String = weakTypeOf[A].toString
    ...
  }

  def getName[A] = macro get_name_impl[A]
}

abstract class GenericInterface[T] {
  def getName: String = MacroSupport.getName[T]
}

case class ContainerA(
  someValue: String
)

class FunctionalClass extends GenericInterface[ContainerA] {
  val containerName: String = getName
}
```

What I hope to achieve is having any number of `FunctionalClass`'s, each with their own `Container` class, and they can report the name of their container, which is used for some meta configuration. Basically `MacroSupport` and `GenericInterface` will exist in a library I'm writing while the `FunctionalClass` and `Container` levels will be written by others using the library.

The issue I'm having, due to the pass through type in the `GenericInterface`, `FunctionalClass.containerName` == "t", and attempts to access Type declarations yield nothing. How can I get the type information from the `FunctionalClass` declaration to the `MacroSupport` level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try materialization of type class

https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/implicits.html#implicit-materializers

```
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox
import scala.language.experimental.macros

object MacroSupport {
  def getName[A](implicit gn: GetName[A]): String = gn()

  trait GetName[A] {
    def apply(): String
  }

  object GetName {
    implicit def materializeGetName[A]: GetName[A] = macro materializeGetNameImpl[A]

    def materializeGetNameImpl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context): c.Expr[GetName[A]] = {
      import c.universe._

      c.Expr[GetName[A]] {
        q"""
          new MacroSupport.GetName[${weakTypeOf[A]}] {
             override def apply(): _root_.java.lang.String = ${weakTypeOf[A].toString}
          }
         """
      }
    }
  }
}

import MacroSupport.GetName

abstract class GenericInterface[T: GetName] {
  def getName: String = MacroSupport.getName[T]
}

case class ContainerA(
                      someValue: String
                     )

class FunctionalClass extends GenericInterface[ContainerA] {
  val containerName: String = getName
}

(new FunctionalClass).containerName // ContainerA
```

By the way, `shapeless.Typeable` does the job. `Typeable[A].describe` is like our `MacroSupport.getName[A]`.

Comment: This is extremely close to what I need, and may prove enough. One issue I'm having out of the gate is that `weakTypeOf[A].toString` yields the full class path for the container class (e.g. "com.X.Y.Z.ContainerA"). I'm digging through trying to find the right accessor to just give the simple name. Accessing the type symbol itself like: `weakTypeOf[A].typeSymbol.toString` yields "class ContainerA". Either of these will work but I'd rather not have to do more string interpolation than is necessary if there is already an accessor that will give the simple name.

Comment: @user675446 Try `weakTypeOf[A].typeSymbol.name.toString`.

Comment: And that does the trick. I've got it all working now, thanks for your help!